# How to make rows of one table data to column names of temporary table

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am getting some number of rows using the query.

```
Select Name 
from UserTypes with(nolock)
```

I need to Append those rows to the columns of the temporary table which already contains 3 static columns.

```
CREATE TABLE #MasterTable
(
  [Functional Area] varchar(150), 
  [Function] varchar(150), 
  [Setting] varchar(150),  
  'My columns should go here...'
)
```

I tried to pivot but it didn't work. I am using sql server 2008.

Answer (score 0):

This is to add the columns to your temp table.

```
select distinct 
    'alter table #MasterTable add [' + [name] + '] varchar(255)' 
from UserTypes with(nolock)
```

If you want to populate these columns, then you didn't say what values you want to put there.